Is ExecuteSqlRawAsync method with parameterized query in ASP .NET Core a proper way of preventing SQL injection attacks?
This is a parametrized query:
string sqlQuery = @"UPDATE MyTable 
                    SET MyTableItemName = @newName 
                    WHERE MyTableItemId = @id;";

await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(
                sqlQuery,
                new SqlParameter("@newName", "Test name"),
                new SqlParameter("@id", 1));

If the parameters will come from a client side, would this query prevent SQL injection attacks?
If not, what would be an alternative besides using LINQ queries?

you could of just read this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlrawasync?view=efcore-8.0

Why? When you can use ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync instead (not that this changes the security in any way).

Any reason you are not using ExecuteUpdateAsync for this particular query?


Is ExecuteSqlRawAsync method with parameterized query in ASP .NET Core
a proper way of preventing SQL injection attacks?

Based on your scenario and description, yes, the ExecuteSqlRawAsync method with parameterized queries, as shown in your example, is a proper way to prevent SQL Injection attacks in ASP.NET Core. Parameterized queries ensure that user input is treated as data rather than executable code, effectively preventing malicious SQL code injection.
However, the ExecuteSqlRawAsync or FromSqlRaw method can be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks if you cannot use them correctly.
When saying use them correctly, means they must be parameterized and property sanitized.
So in order to overcome this concern, from EF core 7.0 FromSql and FromSqlInterpolated has been introduced. These methods are more safe against SQL injection, and always integrate parameter data as a separate SQL parameter you can see details here.
If the parameters will come from a client side, would this query prevent SQL injection attacks?
Yes, it will. The approach you've described with ExecuteSqlRawAsync and SqlParameter objects effectively prevents SQL injection attacks, even when parameters come from client-side sources.
But ensure  objects received from SqlParameter handles value binding and  inputs are sanitized and properly formatted before being sent to the database server.

If not, what would be an alternative besides using LINQ queries?

As an alternative, using LINQ queries or methods provided by EF Core (DbContext and its DbSet properties) to construct queries. EF Core automatically parameterizes queries when using LINQ methods, providing an ORM (Object-Relational Mapping) layer that abstracts SQL interactions.
The code snippet you've shared might be convert into following linq which which would do the same.
var entity = await _context.MyTable.FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.MyTableItemId == id);
if (entity != null)
{
    entity.MyTableItemName = newName;
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}

Real code example:
public async Task UpdateUserName(string userId, string newUserName)
 {
     var user = await _context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == userId);

     if (user != null)
     {
         user.UserName = newUserName;
         await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
     }
     else
     {
         throw new Exception($"User with ID {userId} not found.");
     }
 }

Output:





Note: If you need more information please refer to this official document.
